# Coloring row when condition is met

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to color the cell when condition is met and valid value for package of a product is found in another column in a different sheet.

There is a problem with the if statement.

```vb
Sub validation()

Dim lastRow_s As Long
Dim lastRow_m As Long

lastRow_s = Sheets("product").Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row
lastRow_m = Sheets("product").Cells(Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 2 To lastRow_s
        For j = 2 To lastRow_m
            If Sheets("product").Cells(i,"D").Value = 
                Sheets("valid_package").Cells(j,"A").Value And
                Sheets("product").Cells(i, "H").Value =
                Sheets("valid_package").Cells(j,"B").Value Then
                Sheets("product").Cells(i, "H").Value = vbGreen
            End If
        Next j
    Next i

End Sub
```

I am trying to iterate over two columns to make sure that the product in column D has a valid package in column H in the product sheet. In the valid_package sheet there is a column for product and package that are valid for this products, so valid_package looks like this:

| Product (this is column A from valid package) | Package (this is column B from valid package) |
| --- | --- |
| Product A | 65x3 |
| Product A | 63x3 |
| Product B | 65x3 |
| Product B | 60x3 |
| Product C | 15 |
| Product C | 10x3 |
| Product C | 15 |
| Product D | 10 |

The product sheet is like this if you take only the two columns:

| Product (this is column D from products) | Package (this is column H from products) |
| --- | --- |
| Product A | 65x3 |
| Product C | 63x3 |
| Product B | 65x3 |
| Product C | 60x3 |
| Product A | 15 |
| Product B | 10x3 |
| Product C | 15 |
| Product E | 10 |
| Product C | 15 |
| Product D | 10 |

I want to highlight correct package in column H for sheet product or incorrect package in column H for sheet product, it doesn't matter what is colored.

I get

> Expected: "line number or label or statement or end of statement.

Comment: The linebreaks between `If` and `Then` are likely the problem.

Comment: What error does it raise and on what row? Is it a typo here `Sheet("valid_package")Cells(j,"A")`? A missing dot before `Cells`...? Then, as mentioned above, when you try breaking a line you should ad " _" at the end of those lines. In your case after `And` and after second `Then`. You can accomplish the same task in a faster way, using `Find` and also placing the cells to be validated/colored in a Union Range and color them at once, at the end of the code...

Comment: I have tried to correct it, but it throws: Compile error: Expected: expression now it looks like this
`
    For i = 2 To lastRow_sub
        For j = 2 To lastRow_moc
            If Sheet("product").Cells(i,"D").Value =
                Sheet("valid_package").Cells(j,"A").Value And
                
                Sheet("product").Cells(i, "H").Value
                Sheet("valid_package").Cells(j, "B").Value
            Then
                Sheet("product").Cells(i, "D").Value = vbGreen
            End If
        Next j
    Next i`

Comment: Why not using conditional formatting?

Comment: You also must use `Sheets` instead of `Sheet`... When try correcting do not show us the code in a comment. Please, edit your question and correct it there.

Comment: Do both sheets have the same number of rows for the compared columns?

Comment: No, they don't have the same number of rows.

Comment: Then, your code is a mess,  no offence... You also should use `Rows.count` instead of `Row.count`, which does not have any meaning...

Comment: I know, it is my very first try at VBA.

Comment: But if the number of rows in H:H is bigger than in D:D, your code will miss come rows to be checked. And doing that on the same loop, at least D:D and H:H of the "product" sheet should have the same number of rows. Do they have? If not, I think it is time to explain **in words** what you try accomplishing. Your pseudo code, confuses us instead of helping to better understand your need... Are you sure that the cells **from the same row** in the first sheet must match the the values **from the same row** of the second one?

Comment: "Are you sure that the cells from the same row in the first sheet must match the the values from the same row of the second one?" No they don't.  I have to find them somewhere in the columns of the second sheet.

Comment: At least, are the columns in your code the ones where to find the matching values? I mean D:D with A:A and H:H with B:B? And your explanation correlated to what you added after editing the question does not match too much... Shouldn't the code find a match between The same value in D:D with A:A **and** H:H with B:B? At the first sight, the number of rows should be equal per each sheet. Otherwise, nothing make sense... Is this assumption correct?

Comment: Hi column D from sheet products has the same type of data as column A in sheet valid_package, they have the 'Product A, Product B, Product C'. While column H in sheet products has the same type of data as column B in valid_package. These are columns with '65x3' or '60x3'. The number of rows are not the same for both sheets.

Comment: Did you ever hear of conditional formatting?

Comment: Yes, but I have never used it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Color Conditionally Matching Cells

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub TestAll()
    ValidationQuickFix
    ValidationReadable
    ValidationEfficient
' Result on 1000 matches in 10000 rows of destination 
' with only 10 rows of unique source values:
' Quick Fix: 6,1875
' Readable:  2,21484375
' Efficient: 0,87890625
End Sub

Sub ValidationQuickFix()
    Dim t As Double: t = Timer
    
    ThisWorkbook.Activate
    
    Dim lastRow_s As Long
    lastRow_s = Worksheets("valid_package").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Dim lastRow_d As Long
    lastRow_d = Worksheets("product").Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row

    Dim i As Long, j As Long

    For i = 2 To lastRow_d
        For j = 2 To lastRow_s
            If Worksheets("product").Cells(i, "D").Value = _
                    Worksheets("valid_package").Cells(j, "A").Value Then
                If Worksheets("product").Cells(i, "H").Value = _
                        Worksheets("valid_package").Cells(j, "B").Value Then
                    Worksheets("product").Cells(i, "H").Interior.Color = vbGreen
                Else
                    Worksheets("product").Cells(i, "H").Interior.Color = xlNone
                End If
            End If
        Next j
    Next i

    Debug.Print "Quick Fix: " & Timer - t
End Sub

Sub ValidationReadable()
    Dim t As Double: t = Timer
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Worksheets("valid_package")
    Dim slRow As Long: slRow = sws.Cells(sws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Worksheets("product")
    Dim dlRow As Long: dlRow = dws.Cells(dws.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row

    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    
    For i = 2 To dlRow
        For j = 2 To slRow
            If dws.Cells(i, "D").Value = sws.Cells(j, "A").Value Then
                If dws.Cells(i, "H").Value = sws.Cells(j, "B").Value Then
                    dws.Cells(i, "H").Interior.Color = vbGreen
                Else
                    dws.Cells(i, "H").Interior.Color = xlNone
                End If
            End If
        Next j
    Next i

    Debug.Print "Readable:  " & Timer - t
End Sub

Sub ValidationEfficient()
    Dim t As Double: t = Timer
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Worksheets("valid_package")
    Dim slRow As Long: slRow = sws.Cells(sws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Dim srg1 As Range: Set srg1 = sws.Range("A2:A" & slRow)
    Dim srg2 As Range: Set srg2 = sws.Range("B2:B" & slRow)
    
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Worksheets("product")
    Dim dlRow As Long: dlRow = dws.Cells(dws.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row
    Dim drg1 As Range: Set drg1 = dws.Range("D2:D" & dlRow)
    Dim drg2 As Range: Set drg2 = dws.Range("H2:H" & dlRow)

    Dim ddrg As Range
    Dim dCell As Range
    Dim sIndex As Variant
    Dim dr As Long
    
    For dr = 1 To drg1.Rows.Count
        sIndex = Application.Match(drg1.Cells(dr).Value, srg1, 0)
        If IsNumeric(sIndex) Then
            If drg2.Cells(dr).Value = srg2.Cells(sIndex).Value Then
                If ddrg Is Nothing Then
                    Set ddrg = drg2.Cells(dr)
                Else
                    Set ddrg = Union(ddrg, drg2.Cells(dr))
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next dr

    If Not ddrg Is Nothing Then
        drg2.Interior.Color = xlNone
        ddrg.Interior.Color = vbGreen
    End If

    Debug.Print "Efficient: " & Timer - t
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Please, test the next code. It should be fast, using `Find`, placing the range to be colored in a `Union` range and coloring it at the code end. I hope that I correctly understood what you want and mostly what you have...

```
Sub validation()
Dim shP As Worksheet, shVP As Worksheet, rngColor As Range, rngA As Range, rngB As Range
Dim lastRow_P As Long, lastRow_VP As Long, cellMatch As Range, i As Long

Set shP = Sheets("product")
Set shVP = Sheets("valid_package")
lastRow_P = shP.cells(rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).row
lastRow_VP = shVP.cells(rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row


Set rngA = shVP.Range("A2:A" & lastRow_VP)
For i = 2 To lastRow_P
    Set cellMatch = rngA.Find(what:=shP.cells(i, "D").Value, LookIn:=xlValues, Lookat:=xlWhole)
    If Not cellMatch Is Nothing Then
        If cellMatch.Offset(0, 1).Value = shP.cells(i, "H").Value Then
            If rngColor Is Nothing Then
                Set rngColor = shP.cells(i, "H")
            Else
                Set rngColor = Union(rngColor, shP.cells(i, "H"))
            End If
        End If
    End If
Next i

If Not rngColor Is Nothing Then rngColor.Interior.color = vbGreen
End Sub
```

Comment: You have this typo `valid_packag`: should be `valid_package`.

Comment: @VBasic2008 Yup... Corrected. Thanks! Anyhow, it looks that he couldn't understand too much from the above code... :)

Comment: Thank you I will be now analyzing VBasic2008 and your code to learn something. :) My VBA skills are non-existent, I admit it.